# with git what should I do with .bundle directory?

Tags: git, bundle

Currently my `.bundle` directory is untracked.

Should I `git add .bundle/*`?  I'm not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a Rails 3 project, you should ignore your `.bundle` directory. Add a line to you `.gitignore` file:

```
.bundle
```

So `git status` won't show it again as an untracked directory.

See http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-tricks-tips-workflows/

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't add it to your git repo, **just ignore it**! See what the bundler says in below link:

http://bundler.io/rationale.html

**Checking Your Code into Version Control**

> Do not check in the .bundle directory, or any of the files inside it.
>   Those files are specific to each particular machine, and are used to
>   persist installation options between runs of the bundle install
>   command.